# Using Azure Point-to-Site VPN floods the domain controller with EventId 4768: A Kerberos authentication ticket (TGT) was requested

Tags: azure, windows-authentication, azure-vpn, windows-security

Premises: in Azure `Virtual network gateway` using the `point-to-site` configuration I setup a VPN connection using `Azure certificate` as authentication type; Certificates are generated locally, installed on Windows box; their names are `P2SRootCert` and `P2SChildCert`
I download the `VPN Client` from Azure and installed it on Windows box (that is connected to a domain controller).
As expected the the VPN connection works correctly however, the `Windows Security Event` category on the `domain controller` gets flooded with `4768: A Kerberos authentication ticket (TGT) was requested.`
Stopping the VPN connection stops the above events; the frequency is every 30-50 seconds per event;

The request is using the generated `X509N:<S>CN=P2SClientCert` username derived from the client certificate and it is obviously failing with the "Bad username" 0x6 - status.

Here is a sample of the offending event (slightly edited for brevity and anonymity; 192.168.50.64 is my computer local IP address on the NIC connected to the DC)

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    - <System>
          <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}" /> 
          <EventID>4768</EventID> 
        ...
          <Channel>Security</Channel> 
          <Computer>DC01.mydomain.com</Computer> 
          <Security /> 
      </System>
    - <EventData>
          <Data Name="TargetUserName">X509N:<S>CN=P2SClientCert</Data> 
          <Data Name="TargetDomainName">MYDOMAIN.COM</Data> 
          <Data Name="TargetSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
          <Data Name="ServiceName">krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM</Data> 
          <Data Name="ServiceSid">S-1-0-0</Data> 
          <Data Name="TicketOptions">0x40810010</Data> 
          <Data Name="Status">0x6</Data> 
          <Data Name="TicketEncryptionType">0xffffffff</Data> 
          <Data Name="PreAuthType">-</Data> 
          <Data Name="IpAddress">::ffff:192.168.50.64</Data> 
          <Data Name="IpPort">51683</Data> 
          <Data Name="CertIssuerName" /> 
          <Data Name="CertSerialNumber" /> 
          <Data Name="CertThumbprint" /> 
      </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Question: How can I stop the events from happening?